# He had problems learning and me too or He had problems learning and also I did

Tags: expressions, expression-choice

I want to write it as the second way but I'm not pretty sure if it is the correct way.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

There are some ways:
I had problems learning and so did I.
Or: He had problems learning and me too.
Or: We both had problems learning.
Or: Both of us had problems learning.